# Pressing F5 is not working in VS code to open new window for debugging my custom theme

Tags: visual-studio-code, yeoman-generator

I have created a new custom theme using the Yoeman theme generated and now when I pressed on <kbd>F5</kbd> to open a new Host Extension window of the custom theme it is actually showing me to select environment?

[image]

Comment: Try with Ctrl + Shift + N

Comment: it will simply open a new window of selected vscode. But I want to open a new window of my custom to debug

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have managed to open a new Extension development window by the following step which is not the ideal way to do it but helped me to run it.

I have selected the chrome (preview) option which will create a .vscode folder in your workspace and will have one file `launch.json`.

In your project directory, you will also have a .vscode folder and `launch.json` file inside it. So, I have copied the content of `launch.json` and pasted it in the workspace `launch.json` file.

I don't know the reason how it is get solved with that but happily, I managed to open the new Extension Development Host window.

The reason for not showing up the `Extension Development Host` window by pressing F5 in the first place is because my VS code workspace is not inside the project directory. The project directory contains the setup for launching the `Extension Development Host` window in `launch.json`. So, If I want to suggest then I would say that `VS code workspace needs to be inside the project folder directory`.

Answer (score 5):

You must open the project root directory not the directory that wraps project root.
In my case, `test1` was the root directory.

**DO NOT**

[image]

**DO**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You must close all open files and **open the root directory of your new extension/theme you'd like to test!**

Ex: here is the layout, as shown by `tree`, of my folder which contains my extension/color theme I'm working on:

```
├── gs-my-theme2
│   ├── CHANGELOG.md
│   ├── package.json
│   ├── README.md
│   ├── themes
│   │   └── GS my theme name-color-theme.json
│   └── vsc-extension-quickstart.md
```

So, I go to File --> Open Folder... --> navigate to `/home/gabriel/GS/dev/vscode_GS/gs-my-theme2` in my case to open the **gs-my-theme2** folder. Now, when I press <kbd>F5</kbd>, it works! It opens up a brand new VSCode window which is running my theme/extension!

Prior to first **opening this folder** in VSCode, and closing all other files, I just got a weird dropdown menu whenever I pressed <kbd>F5</kbd>, and it wouldn't really do anything.

References:

1. Seeing what is *supposed* to happen when you press <kbd>F5</kbd>, in this video at 12:08~12:12, helped!: https://youtu.be/FeApSxfazVg?t=728

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone comes to this page because they aren't able to get this working with a pre-existing extension they cloned and want to modify, I ended up using the Yeoman generator [mentioned in the docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/extension-guides/color-theme#create-a-new-color-theme) and found the difference is in the `.vscode/launch.json` file. This folder is typically ignored by git, so you'll have to add it manually if you clone another extension.

Just place the following code in `.vscode/launch.json` and you should be good to go:

```
// A launch configuration that launches the extension inside a new window
// Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
// Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
// For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Extension",
      "type": "extensionHost",
      "request": "launch",
      "args": ["--extensionDevelopmentPath=${workspaceFolder}"]
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You press F1 type "Generate Assets for Build and Debug" then try again

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).